# MDX Running total on every date member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I use the following MDX calculation to get the stock value per day:

```
    SUM({NULL:[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER} * [Measures].[Qty])
```

However this is giving me the following result

Date             QtyOnHand

1/1/2015               10

4/1/2015               15

5/1/2015               16

Mark that the dates 2/1/2015 and 3/1/2015 are not shown, because there are no transactions on them.
I would like to get these  shown to get the following result:

Date             QtyOnHand

1/1/2015               10

2/1/2015               10

3/1/2015               10

4/1/2015               15

5/1/2015               16

How can I adjust my MDX statement to this?

Answer (score 0):

Does `IsEmpty` help?

```
SUM(
  {NULL:[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER} 
* IIF(
   IsEmpty([Measures].[Qty])
   ,0
   ,[Measures].[Qty]
  )
)
```

If it helps then it won't help performance.

---

I've tested the above and unsure why you do the cross-join inside the `Sum` - more standard is just to use the second argument.

This `AdvWrks` script is an example of your scenario i.e. there are gaps in the data:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,{
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20051201]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Here is the query using `IsEmpty` (with `IIF`):

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[roll] AS 
    Sum
    (
      {[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801] : [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}
     ,IIF
      (
        IsEmpty([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
       ,0
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[roll]} ON 0
 ,{
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050801]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20051201]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Some of the results are the following:

[image]

So in your scenario I think this is very similar:

```
SUM(
  {NULL:[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER} 
, IIF(
   IsEmpty([Measures].[Qty])
   ,0
   ,[Measures].[Qty]
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the IsEmpty only requires one argument. You specify 2.

Comment: @OverflowStack thanks - we can then use it inside an `IIF` function.

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour as before. screenshots: The pivot http://postimg.org/image/o1pj65nkd/  the mdx: http://postimg.org/image/534uacfcf/

Comment: @OverflowStack if you create a diagnostic measure defined as `[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.member_caption` and add that to the pivot what does it show? I'm interested to know what the currentmember is for the last row in your pivot.